# How to add config file for class library project?

Tags: c#

I have make dll from class library projects and then these dlls are used in main application. Now i am facing 417 expectation failed error when calling a function of dll. When i placed  in app.config file of main application then it is running fine. But i want to handle this thing in class library project so that the user should not add manually this specific line to their configuarion setting

Comment: Is that method/function internally calling any WCF service?

Comment: no i am just sending httpwebrequest to server

Answer (score 3):

TBH, I would consider referencing a configuration file from a library as bad practice for exactly the reason you mentioned - it isn't obvious to consumers of the library what the dependencies are.

Personally, I would have your library requesting settings as part of the relevant constructor/s.

Answer (score 1):

A class library project results in a dll added to your main project. Your main project should have all the settings in its config file. That's the whole idea of config files. You can hard-code the value in the dll in several ways, but that defeats the purpose as your project will not have the chance to change this value in its config file.

The developer(s) of your main project should know the requirements of each dll they add to the project. If you don't want this dependency, then you can build the functions in your class library in a way that they expect the config values as parameters. This way, the main project will be the one responsible of managing the values (hopefully in the config file) and passing them to the dll functions when calling them.

Comment: sir i want to set expectation10 continue value and it is not working when i set it manually

Comment: @MuneemHabib I'm sorry, I did not get what you said. What is "expectation10 continue value"? And how do you "set it manually"?

Comment: System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;

Comment: @MuneemHabib And what is wrong with that? I don't see how this is related to you question. You need to either edit your question and add the relevant info so we can help you, or start another question.